# Semantic UI, difference between table and grid?

Tags: semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'd like to create a multiple rows + multiple columns view.

I think I can either use table or grid.

Which one should I use over another and why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Summary**

> Grid
>
> Using a grid makes content appear to flow more naturally on your page.
>
> Table
>
> A standard table.

from [Semantic-UI](https://semantic-ui.com)

**Explained**

Grids

> The CSS Grid Layout specification is one of a few new specifications
>   that are redefining how we approach layout for the web. Alongside
>   Flexbox and the Box Alignment Module it will become part of a modern
>   layout system for websites and web applications.

from [Grid by Example](http://gridbyexample.com/)

Table

Table is just a layout, and could be complex for complex views. Just think in spreadsheets. You can merge columns and rows to get your layout.

**Opinion**

You can use the option you want, according to your needs. But if you are looking to organize your web content, use grids; If you need to deploy data use tables.

Answer (score 0):

That all depends on the requirement. for example, If you want them to maximize the use of the page; maybe for a report with multiple columns over the whole webpage and you knew beforehand on what device your page would be rendered then use a table because you can pinpoint each and every column to exact pixels.

But if the rendering device might be any device or the rendering device info is not available then use grid because it would automatically adjust to the available layout space.